# What is the purpose of the improvements tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

The [improvements](/questions/tagged/improvements) tag seems redundant as all [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s are improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it has been deleted.